# Pandas: Is there a way to group together values within a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to crunch a DataFrame in which one column is called `"Rank"`, for military rank.  When I use `groupby` on the data and create a `crosstab`, I notice that some of the values in `Rank` are synonyms. For example, I have separate rows in my cross table for "Private 1st Class," "Private First Class," and "PFC."

**Assuming** I can manually create a dictionary to relate all of those "synonyms" together, is there a way I can get pandas to apply it to my DataFrame so that the values are all considered the same for the purposes of counts, crosstables, and so on?  So for the example above, if I decided to standardize on "PFC" I would create the following: `{"Private 1st Class": "PFC", "Private First Class": "PFC"}`.

I looked at `groupby`, but as far as I can tell it sorts the whole frame by columns, and doesn't support equivalent values like this.  If I'm wrong, could someone please point me to the relevant part of the documentation?

Comment: Could you create a new column in your data frame containing the "standardized rank" and `groupby` on that new column?

Comment: Take your dictionary, turn it into a pandas `dataframe`, `merge` it with the original and `groupby` the new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show you an example:

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1,2,3,4,5], "key": ["Private 1st class", "Private First Class", "PFC", "other", "other"]})
```

Translation dictonary:

```
translate = pd.DataFrame.from_records({"key": ["Private 1st class", "PFC", "Private First Class"],
                           "harmonizedkey": ["PFC", "PFC", "PFC"]})
```

Let's merge the dict to `df`:

```
newdf = pd.merge(df, translate, how = "left", on = "key")
```

Create a new (complete) group:

```
newdf["newgroup"] = newdf["harmonizedkey"].combine_first(newdf["key"])
newdf

    key                 val harmonizedkey   newgroup
0   Private 1st class   1   PFC             PFC
1   Private First Class 2   PFC             PFC
2   PFC                 3   PFC             PFC
3   other               4   NaN             other
4   other               5   NaN             other
```

Now, use `groupby`:

```
newdf.groupby("newgroup").sum()

        val
newgroup    
PFC     6
other   9
```

Answer (score 0):

use map with your dictionary to generate the new column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('Private 1st Class', 3),
    ('Private First Class', 2),
    ('PFC', 5),
    ('Sergeant', 2),
    ('SGT', 2)
], columns = ['rank', 'bannanas'])

d = {
    'Private 1st Class': 'PFC',
    'Private First Class': 'PFC',
    'PFC': 'PFC',
    'Sergeant': 'SGT',
    'SGT': 'SGT'
}

df['merged_rank'] = df['rank'].map(d)
print(df)
                  rank  bannanas merged_rank
0    Private 1st Class         3         PFC
1  Private First Class         2         PFC
2                  PFC         5         PFC
3             Sergeant         2         SGT
4                  SGT         2         SGT

print(df.groupby('merged_rank')['bannanas'].agg('sum'))   

merged_rank
PFC    10
SGT     4
Name: bannanas, dtype: int64
```